# union multiset javaCode to python (in range)

Tags: java, python

I'm having troubles converting a Multiset Class in java to Python. Im having a particular problem with this
 this piece of Java-Code to Python:

```
public Multiset unionWith(Multiset other)
{
    Multiset result = new Multiset();

    for ( Object object : elts.keySet() )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i != elts.get(object); ++i )
        {
            result.add(object);
        }
    }

    for ( Object object : other.elts.keySet() )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i != other.elts.get(object); ++i )
        {
            result.add(object);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

This is the entire Class I have made. Everything seems to work except unionWith, Which I can't figure out.I'm pretty sure the problem is with the 'in range', with a condition. How does this work in python?

```
class Multiset:
def __init__(self):
   self.elts= dict()

def contains(self, o):
    if o in self.elts.keys():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def add(self, o):
    if self.contains(o):
        newValue = self.elts.get(o) + 1
        self.elts[o] = newValue
    else:
        self.elts[o] = 1

def remove(self, o):
    if self.contains(o):
        newValue = self.elts.get(o) - 1

        if newValue > 0:
            self.elts[o] = newValue
        else:
            del self.elts[o]


def elements(self):
    return set(self.elts.keys())
@property
def size(self):
    total = 0

    for object in self.elts.values():
        total = total + self.elts.get(object)

    return total
def unionWith(self,other):
    result= Multiset()

    for object in self.elts.values():

        for i in range(0):
            if i is not self.elts.get(object):
                break
            result.add(object)

    for object in other.elts.values():
        for i in range(0):
            if i is not other.get(object):
                break
            result.add(object)
```

Comment: I get the feeling that you're writing `for i in range(0):` with the intent that it should mean "iterate upwards from zero forever", but that's not what it does. What it does is: "iterate through all the values between 0 (inclusive) and 0 (exclusive)". If you want to iterate upwards from zero forever, try `itertools.count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the magic methods to make your class more integrated with python language, like `__iter__` and `__contains__`:

```
import collections
import itertools

class Multiset:
    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        self._data = collections.defaultdict(int)
        if iterable:
            self._data.update(collections.Counter(iterable))

    def __contains__(self, element):
        return element in self._data

    def add(self, element):
        self._data[element] += 1

    def remove(self, element):
        if element not in _data:
            raise KeyError(element)
        elif self._data[element] == 1:
            del self._data[element]
        else:
            self._data[element] -= 1

    def update(self, iterable):
        data = collections.Counter(self._data) + collections.Counter(iterable)
        self._data = collections.defaultdict(int)
        self._data.update(data)

    def elements(self):
        return self._data.keys()

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(self._data.values())

    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.chain.from_iterable(
            itertools.repeat(element, number) 
                for element, number in self._data.items()
        )

    def union(self, other):
        result = Multiset(self)
        result.update(other)
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Multiset([{}])'.format(
            ', '.join(repr(element) for element in self))
```

Testing:

```
>>> s = Multiset()
>>> s
Multiset([])
>>> s.update('abca')
>>> s
Multiset(['a', 'a', 'c', 'b'])
>>> len(s) # calls __len__
>>> 'a' in s  # calls __contains__
True
>>> r = Multiset('zxc')
>>> r
Multiset(['x', 'c', 'z'])
>>> s.union(r)
Multiset(['a', 'a', 'x', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'z'])
```

More could be implemented, like `__add__`, `__sub__` (difference), `intersection`...